# Building a tool to fix compiler errors automagically

Tags: compiler, startup, artificial-intelligence, design

When a program doesn't compile, error messages are sometimes esoteric. Often a simple Google search leading to a site like stack exchange solves the problem. Now why can't we automate this?

How about a Siri for coding? By Siri, I mean an intelligent personal assistant. Not talking about speech recognition here.

I wonder if there is anybody out there (startups/ research labs) building a cool product like this. It will cut down debugging time drastically.

Comment: Have you ever used Eclipse? For some types of compiler errors, it tries to suggest fixes, such as adding the proper `import` statement, fixing build paths, etc... and if you click the little button beside the suggestion, it can (in some cases) *implement* the suggestion such as adding/removing `import` statements. There are limits to what it can do, of course, but it's nice to have and makes some types of compiler errors much less tedious to deal with.

Comment: Have you tried using any static analysis tools on your source *before* compiling? Most IDEs will auto compile as you type (or save), and the errors should be obvious within a line or two (and even get built in suggestions from the IDE).  When it isn't something "trivial", how many different possible meanings of the source are there?

Comment: Debugging is by far more demanding process than fixing typos.

Comment: The Eclipse feature is called "Quick Fix", see more here: See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_Quick_Fix%3F

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/30242/7043

Comment: I don't think it's that nobody has thought of it as much as it is an extremely ambitious venture and nobody thus far has been able to achieve that level of intelligence.  The best we have managed to do thus far is indicate probable mistakes like dead code and operation priority.

Comment: If such a product gets built, it will be the equivalent of the A-bomb in computing. The first person to commercialize that without getting eaten by Microsoft and Google will be a multi-billionaire in short order.

Comment: Resharper is another tool that does a reasonably good job at auto-suggesting corrections/alterations to resolve or improve code issues.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers cannot divine your intent, that's why.

Have you ever gotten some obscure error like

> Cannot infer the type of x

only to find out you were missing a semicolon or comma?  That's because the compiler doesn't have something it needs (a critical token), but it doesn't know why.  If it can't figure that out, how's it supposed to figure out that you really do need that cast?

Naturally, we can write better compilers.  But it's an ongoing work in progress, and I suspect that the quality of the language design has a lot to do with it.  Static typing and compile-time assertions are probably the most promising ways to give the compiler the ability to check for errors.

**See Also**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787960/what-makes-haskells-type-system-more-powerful-than-other-languages-type-syst

Comment: The compiler can, however do far better than say "cannot infer the type of x". Off the top of my head, it could have a large Beisian net for computing the conditional probabilities of various error causes, given the whole program written.

Answer (score 1):

It's been done, long ago.  The Cornell [PL/C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/C) compiler for the PL/I language, auto-fixed any problems it found, with the goal of **always** producing a compilable and runnable program, no matter how little it resembled the original input.  Some of the changes were simple, and made good sense.  Others were not.  It was a common joke at the time to drop a deck of randomly-selected punched cards into PL/C and see what happened :-)